# Using jQuery's serializeArray with Rails forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm trying to display an order summary on the final screen of a checkout process (buit in Rails 3). Nothing is submitted prior to this, so I'm using jQuery's `serializeArray()` to get all the names and values from the form fields, which works great. I collect a variety of nested attributes, so the returned array is rather busy, with names like `order[donations_attributes][0][amount_in_dollars]`.

Is there a straightforward way, in Javascript (or using jQuery) to convert those names and values to a JSON string (which would make it way easier to work with to produce my summary output). For example, something like:

```
{
  "order": {
    "donations_attributes": [
      {
        "amount_in_dollars": 50.95,
        "category": "Some Fund"
      },
      {
        "amount_in_dollars": 90.92,
        "category": "Some Other Fund"
      }
    ],
    "billing_address_attributes": {
      "first_name": "Bob",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "address1": "123 Whatever Street",
      "and so on": "etc"
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that I haven't submitted anything yet (nor can I), so I can't do it in Ruby. Is there a sort of obvious, straightforward way to do this, or will I need to parse out and build the string by hand?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass that data as-is to the `data` parameter in `JQuery.ajax(...)`, and it will end up in `parama` in the controller method and view for the action you call, .e.g `params[:order][:donations_attributes][0][:category] == "Some Fund"`.

If you want to load a new url into the browser, you can use `JQuery.serialize()` on the data and append it to your url (with a `"?" in between) to create the URL with the appropriate query string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after reading up on `jQuery.ajax()`, it's not clear to me how this gets me the JSON string I'm looking for without a submit. (If it helps, I'm using mustache.js to generate the order summary. This all has to be done without making a request to the server.)